# Descobrir próximo múltiplo de 10 de um numero no php

Tags: php

Como descobrir o próximo numero que seja múltiplo de 10 no PHP?

Exemplo:

```
$a = 142;
```

Como pegar o numero 150?

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde.
Bom não sei se existe uma função específica para isso, mas podes fazer desta maneira utilizando o `ceil`, e uma lógica matemática simples.

Exemplo:

```
$num = 142;
$arredondado = (ceil($num/10))*10;

//resultado 150;
    echo $arredondado;
```

Simplesmente divida o número por 10, e o arredonde para cima para pegar o próximo número, depois basta voltar a multiplicar por 10 e tem-se o número desejado.

Como eu disse, não sei tem uma função específica, mas funciona.

Espero que ajude.

Att;

Comment: Valeu! resolvido!

Comment: Por favor, coloque como resposta caso tenha resolvido seu problema. Grato

Comment: Poderia tirar as aspas desnecessárias, já que é uma função `$arredondado = ceil($num/10)*10;`

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente isso:

```
round( $a + 4, -1 );
```

Aplicado ao seu código:

```
$a = 142;
echo round( $a + 4, -1 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/itvrff)**.

Round serve para arredondamento de números em `n` casas decimais, mas se usar números negativos, passa a se referir às dezenas, centenas etc.

O -1 é de 10 em 10, -2 de 100 em 100, e assim por diante.

O +4 serve para arredondar sempre para cima (o PHP tem uma constante para escolher este comportamento em decimais, mas que não funciona direito para dezenas) - notar que isso só faz sentido para inteiros. Se for pra uso com decimais, melhor a solução do @Fleuquer